# Why does count fails when no match is found?

Tags: javascript

```
var _myTxt;
var _myWord;
var _count;
var _count2;

function _findWord() {
    _myTxt = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;
    _myWord = document.getElementById('myTxtField').value;
    var re = new RegExp(_myWord, "gi");
    _myTxt = _myTxt.replace(re, "<span style='font-weight: bold'>$&</span>");
    _count = _myTxt.match(re);
    _count2 = _count.length;
    alert(_count.length); // alert returns nothing when there is 0 match ?!
    if (_count < 1) {
        document.getElementById("_idProcessedTxt").innerHTML = "There is no matching occurence for searched word";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("_idProcessedTxt").innerHTML = _myTxt;
        document.getElementById("_idProcessedTxt2").innerHTML = ("Your word was matched : " + _count2 + " times.");
    }
}
```

Hi, the above code is supposed to:

1. replace a string by another string (actually same string with span tags) and
2. count number of times occurrences / replacement was found.

It works well for all cases where there is at least one or more matches. For some reason I don't understand, it doesn't work when the word entered returns no match at all. This seems to totally break code, even the alert returns nothing when there is 0 match.

Any clue why?

Comment: Can you post the code on http://jsbin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ and edit your question to include the link?

Comment: any reason you use `_count.length` in your return when you already made `_count2`?

Comment: This would be a good time to learn about the JavaScript error console.

Comment: Your logic is going to have some issues when the word to search for is "weight" or "bold" or "span" :)

Comment: haha pointy, yes, but this is another story!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `.match()` finds no matches, it returns `null`. Thus, when "_count" is `null`, the next line:

```
_count2 = _count.length;
```

will cause an error (that you would see in your developer console!).

When `.match()` *does* find one or more matches, it returns an array. Thus this subsequent code in your function:

```
    if (_count < 1) {
```

doesn't make any sense because you're comparing an array to a number.

Comment: For the OP's benefit, you likely intended to use `_count2` in the `if` statement that Pointy pointed out.

Comment: @user2532739 yes, that would work if the code to set "_count2" were fixed. Alternatively he could just check to see if "_count" isn't null.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried to check for null or undefined in the if statement as it is in the code, and it didn't worked. So what I did is put the if statement right after     _count =  _myTxt.match(re); before the .length is called. Now it works fine. Cool.